# What video or imagery was captured onboard Cassini during its descent into Saturn's atmosphere?

Tags: saturn, cassini

I'm very interested to see first person what Saturn's upper atmosphere looked like as Cassini began its descent into it.

What footage exists of this, an where can it be viewed?
(I'm not interested in CGI simulations of 'what it would have looked like'.)

If none exists, why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raw images of Cassini can be viewed online in reverse order https://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/galleries/raw-images?order=earth_date+desc&per_page=50&page=0

Comment: So the last image looks like it was taken Sep. 14, 2017 7:59 PM according to that jpl site.  Blurry perhaps from the beginnings of the atmosphere?

Answer (score 2):

As for the question, "why not (why no film/more photos etc.)", the [limited data rate available](https://www.space.com/38154-cassini-saturn-spacecraft-final-hours.html) for Cassini meant they had to limit the amount of photos taken in the last few hours.