# What was Cassini's last image?

Tags: saturn, cassini, deorbit

NASA's Cassini spacecraft made its final approach to Saturn and dove into the planet’s atmosphere on Friday, Sept. 15, 2017. Loss of contact with the Cassini spacecraft took place on Sept. 15 after which it disintegrated out of existence, with **ABSOLUTELY NOTHING** left of it. But My question is, did Cassini send any images before, during, or right before disintegration? If so, are they available to the public to see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to [What video or imagery was captured onboard Cassini during its descent into Saturn's atmosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23457/40489)

The second answer indicates the plan was to not give priority to taking snaps during its plunge:

> Today (Sept. 14) at 3:58 p.m. EDT (1958 GMT; 12:58 p.m. PDT), Cassini will snap its final photo, targeting the patch of atmosphere where it will meet its fiery fate. (**Cassini won't be taking photos during the actual death dive** on Friday; *information will be at a premium*, and *images would hog too much bandwidth*, mission team members said.)

https://www.space.com/38154-cassini-saturn-spacecraft-final-hours.html

So, given the information above, and the links below, the final image from Cassini was taken at *1959 on September 14th 2017*.

Not sure if you looked for this?

Cassini's Final Images

https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/13120/cassinis-final-images/

Cassini Raw Images

https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/raw-images/cassini-raw-images/?order=earth_date+desc&per_page=50&page=0

[image]

> 

```
Image of Saturn
File name: W00110282.jpg
Taken: Sep. 14, 2017 7:59 PM
Received: Sep. 15, 2017 7:04 AM
```

> The camera was pointing toward SATURN, and the image was taken using the CL1 and CL2 filters. This image has not been validated or calibrated. A validated/calibrated image will be archived with the NASA Planetary Data System.

https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/12735

[image]

> The last image Cassini sent back on Sept. 15, 2017 shows the area where it would impact Saturn's atmosphere.

Comment: hey, I've got some nice imagery right here! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_dRetosrLQ

Comment: i hope someday they livestream what happens to a space probe sent into a gas giant, they should build it bulky enough to withstand the mariana trench and then send it to its doom